# Error trying to host a web site asp.net on IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

i'm using `IIS 8.0` ( couldn't download the 7.0 version).
It's my first time working with `web applications`. I used to work with `winforms`.
I `added new Web Site`, then I selected the folder of my asp.net + C# solution then converted the folder to an `application`  on `IIS`.Now I'm gettint an error. Also, I changed the `frameWork version` to `v4.0`

`Erro HTTP 500.19 - Internal Server Error`
`The required page couldn't be accessed because the configuration data of the page are invalid`

```
33:<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
 34:<handlers>
 35:<add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
```

Comment: Do you have ReportViewer installed on the server or in your bin folder for the website?

Comment: @RyanMcDonough Gee, I dont know. My idea was to leave it on our server computer. But for now, it's on my local machine, just for some tests... I don't know tell you... When I used it I just `drag/drop` from the `toolbox`. Could you give me some help? PLEASE? As I said, it's my first time working with WEB, so I dont't know much x.x

Comment: @RyanMcDonough Now I get no Errorrs... But my page localhost:90 just show the name of my folders... Where's the page?